# Menu token not working properly

Tags: navigation, 7

I am Using menu token module to access pages related particular user, I am getting issue while selecting path in token menu using replacement patterns. can any one explains on what basis it will take the link and direct to the page. i tried to use [node:content-type:name], As there are so many content types created in my site, so how it will take the specific content type which is related with the node.

kindly suggest me if there are alternatives for this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you've chosen the right method under "MENU TOKEN OPTIONS":

[image: snapshot]

With this options enabled, I was able to create a menu item using the token `[node:content-type:name]`

Comment: for path if i use token as "user/[current-user:uid]" it is taking as user/1 for 1st user and user/2 for second user respectively. but if i use any token other than "[current-user:uid]", it is showing the token name in the link  (example. if i select token [node:content-type:name] it is not redirecting to specific page)

Comment: Kindly suggest any other menu modules which has similar functionality to redirect to the pages to logged in user contains their own data

Comment: @Manukumar You have to select "Node from context" as I have mentioned above. It seems that you have selected "users from context" option and not the other. And tokens work fine and are very useful. But, they only appear when the condition is valid, which I think is right.